# Call Dialer Issue in Android

Tags: android

I've created a custom dialer in android obviously as project requirement. So my question is when user dials some number he should have seen option to select my custom dialer with default dialer. If he chooses mine dialer he should redirect to my custom dialer. So how to register my created custom dialer to android ?

Regards,
Shishir Shetty.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working

```
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyDialerApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

but there a problem, this is not showing the application in application menu.
please, how can i set the application action main as well as dial

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the manifest to let your activity handle these events?
Its something similar to this:

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

A complete example can be found here: http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-intents-and-intent-filters/

Answer (score 0):

add this to your activities intent filter.

```
<intent-filter ><action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /><data android:scheme="tel" />
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an intent filter to your manifest, like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

There are other options explained at some length here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html